# Firestore rules aren't working for users following official documentation

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So I am running my Flutter app locally with emulators. The firestore rules are copied from the docs:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
          allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
          allow create: if request.auth != null;
        }
  }
}
```

After I signup the user successfully I try to create his doc like this:

```dart
UserCredential userCredential = await auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: data.name!, password: data.password!);
await auth.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification();
DocumentReference ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
await ref.set({"isOwner":false},SetOptions(merge: true));
```

This results in the error:

> W/Firestore(17604): (24.4.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at
> users/JknXHMkWb0jL4ohiW18K9h6NLyyB: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED,
> description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Does it need time to get the uid? I can't think of anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Foundation.kDebugMode) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080);
}
```

Found this on some google group. Moving the clearPersistence line below the firestore emulator made it work. This is really non-standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Look out as well into the debugging output of your app : the Firebase Firestore SDK outputs a debug token for you to whitelist your test device on *Firebase > AppCheck > Apps*.

From there, look for the 3-dots menu of the platform you're debugging onto, click it, and select "Manage debug tokens" : add the token here.

From my observations, this debug token doesn't live forever. If experience again permissions issues, try re-adding the token which you get in the debug output.